# prevent access to files in folder with a golang server

Tags: go, server

I've a server in golang who handle folder path like that :

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets"))
http.Handle("/Images/", fs)
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```

But in this folder there are privates images, and it shouldn't be possible to access files. So how can i secure image access and prevent anybody to access content of folder.

like that for example :

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you don't want people to access these images but other files in the same folder?

Comment: @xen I dont want people access to file in this folder with folder path

Comment: It this your issue? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/bStLPdIVM6w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to block a directory using `http` package, maybe this will be useful to you :

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/bStLPdIVM6w
>
> ```
> package main
>
> import (
>   "net/http"
>   "os"
> )
>
> type justFilesFilesystem struct {
>   fs http.FileSystem
> }
>
> func (fs justFilesFilesystem) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
>   f, err := fs.fs.Open(name)
>   if err != nil {
>       return nil, err
>   }
>   return neuteredReaddirFile{f}, nil
> }
>
> type neuteredReaddirFile struct {
>   http.File
> }
>
> func (f neuteredReaddirFile) Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error) {
>   return nil, nil
> }
>
> func main() {
>   fs := justFilesFilesystem{http.Dir("/tmp/")}
>   http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.FileServer(fs))
> }
> ```

Comment: but what should i do with this line : fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets")) ??

Comment: I think you have to replace `http.Dir("/tmp/")` with `http.Dir("./assets")`

Comment: Ok it works perfectly but my api on this server no longer works, so should I make 2 servers?

Comment: I have no idea how your server works, i can't tell you is you should or shouldn't have a second server. Maybe try to close this question and open a new one explaining your new problem !

Answer (score 1):

A little wrapper over FileServer() solves your problem, now you have to add some sort of logic to do Authorization, it looks like you have unique names, that's good, so I just filter the image name for you creating a map of names, now you can add something more dynamic like a key/store(memcached, redis. etc.) Hope you can follow the comments

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

// put the allowed hashs or keys here
// you may consider put them in a key/value store
//
var allowedImages = map[string]bool{
    "key-abc.jpg": true,
    "key-123.jpg": true,
}

func main() {

    http.Handle("/Images/", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        // here we can do any kind of checking, in this case we'll just split the url and
        // check if the image name is in the allowedImages map, we can check in a DB or something
        //
        parts := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")
        imgName := parts[len(parts)-1]

        if _, contains := allowedImages[imgName]; !contains { // if the map contains the image name

            log.Printf("Not found image: %q path: %s\n", imgName, r.URL.Path)

            // if the image is not found we write a 404
            //
            // Bonus: we don't list the directory, so nobody can know what's inside :)
            //
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }

        log.Printf("Serving allowed image: %q\n", imgName)

        fileServer := http.StripPrefix("/Images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets")))

        fileServer.ServeHTTP(w, r) // StripPrefix() and FileServer() return a Handler that implements ServerHTTP()
    }))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ehrd_AWXim

Comment: it's not exactly what i need know but thanks, I'm sure one day I'll need this example :)