# Golang html template cannot call javascript file in html file

Tags: javascript, go

I bundle React app with Webpack after I call it in HTML file. However, it error when I using Golang and html/template to view HTML file.
My HTML file: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Note App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="public/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Golang file: index.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
    "path/filepath"
)

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fp := filepath.Join("views", "index.html")
    t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(fp))
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @V5NXT Please don't use snippets for Go language code; they only work for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 8):

The issue seems to be that you are spinning up a server that only serves the HTML template - not the script. When a browser attempts to load your scripts, the server returns your index page.

Take a look at https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/serving-static-sites-with-go; this post discusses how you can serve static files.

For your purposes, you may be able to get by just by adding the following lines to the beginning of your main method:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

This will load any files in your directory, "public" (relative to your compiled executable), and serve them at url/public/path/to/file

As a word of caution: by default, this will enable directory listings for your public directory (users will be able to see a list of files in that directory and all subdirectories). Take a look at the answer for this question for info on how to disable directory listings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40718195/6346483

Answer (score 0):

Are you serving `public/bundle.js`?

If not you need to serve it somehow. For example you can use `net/http` https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile