# Block direct file calls on the http server

Tags: http, go, web, block

How to block direct calls on the Go http server? I would not like the user to be able to make a direct call, example: `http://localhost:8080/home.html`, but only `http://localhost:8080/home/`.

I tried the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716869/prevent-access-to-files-in-folder-with-a-golang-server), but i received route errors, example: `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

server.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.HandleFunc("/home/", homeHandler)
    log.Println("\nRunning...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

home.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    switch {
    case r.Method == "GET" :
        http.ServeFile(w,r,"public/home.html")
    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sorry... :(")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `FileServer` is explicitly exposing those files. If you don't want that, don't do it.

Comment: I do not want access to be done by calling the file in the browser. But that is done by the route, so as not to skip the authentication

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mschoebel/9398202/raw/32fa5c1ab8f8741f2bac6c85532e0ddee3e7824b/main.go

Comment: It helped me adjust the logic, I hope it helps others in the future

Answer (score 2):

Deleting these two lines

```golang
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
```

from server.go will work. By `work` I mean you get 404 by visiting localhost:8080/home.html while the file is served as expected on localhost:8080/home

Comment: You're right, it really worked, but it doesn't load the Javascript and CSS files, any suggestions?

Comment: @LuisHenrique: Looks like you have contradicting requirements. On the one side you don't want to provide direct access to the files inside public. On the other side you want this access because the CSS and Javascript files are stored there - and these should be available for direct access. I think you need to make more clear how exactly your setup is, what files should be accessible directly and what files not. For example you could simply put all files which should be directly accessible  into public and put all other files somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is that if the user is able to call the file directly in the browser, he skips the login screen

Comment: @LuisHenrique, if accessing home.html requires authorization it isn't "public", is it? So don't put it in the public directory.

Comment: you're right, I fixed it, thanks

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mschoebel/9398202/raw/32fa5c1ab8f8741f2bac6c85532e0ddee3e7824b/main.go

Comment: It helped me in solved